# Failed to create collection 'techproducts' due to: Underlying core creation failed while creating collection: techproducts

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I just started to learn solr with official documentation and during the first exercise "Index Techproducts Example Data" I failed due to following error: " Failed to create collection 'techproducts' due to: Underlying core creation failed while creating collection: techproducts".

I tried to change java version from 13 to 8 but it didn't helped.

Here is link to the documentation: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/solr-tutorial.html#exercise-1

Stacktrace from solr Admin console

```
Collection: techproducts operation: create failed:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Underlying core creation failed while creating collection: techproducts
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.api.collections.CreateCollectionCmd.call(CreateCollectionCmd.java:304)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.api.collections.OverseerCollectionMessageHandler.processMessage(OverseerCollectionMessageHandler.java:263)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.OverseerTaskProcessor$Runner.run(OverseerTaskProcessor.java:504)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:210)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: The Solr log should tell you what went wrong. Check the log and add the relevant information to your question.

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh. Updated

Comment: There should be another error message - i.e. the reason why the underlying core creation failed. It might be related to permissions, but the stack trace should show a message as well.

Comment: 6/26/2020, 9:01:34 PM
ERROR false
OverseerCollectionMessageHandler
Error from shard: http://192.168.1.42:7574/solr

Comment: there is no more than this. I cannot find log files. Maybe there is something more ...

Comment: Check the log in the instance running on `:7574`, not the one running on `:8983`.

Comment: After I restarted my mac it started working. Thanks @MatsLindh for your engagement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had run into similar situation while following Solr
's official tutorial as following

```
➜  solr-8.7.0 ERROR: Failed to create collection 'techproducts' due to: Underlying core creation failed while creating collection: techproducts
```

**And problem solved my turning off my vpn.** I guess the vpn routing probably messed up with solr's **localhost** setting somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same *Underlying core creation failed...* error too.  Using Java 11, Windows 10.

The log file was *${solr-home}\example\cloud\node1\logs\solr.log*.  Inside it had:

`org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://192.168.1.16:7574/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'techproducts_shard1_replica_n1': Unable to create core [techproducts_shard1_replica_n1] Caused by: no segments* file found in LockValidatingDirectoryWrapper(NRTCachingDirectory(MMapDirectory@{solr_home}\example\cloud\node2\solr\techproducts_shard1_replica_n1\data\index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@16326253; maxCacheMB=48.0 maxMergeSizeMB=4.0)): files: [write.lock] at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:681) ~[?:?]`
`at (etc. etc.)e`

But this was the second time I launched solr.  The first time it timed out trying to contact one of the nodes and the tutorial script aborted.  But the nodes were still running.  I killed them off using the windows task manager and not by using *solr stop*.  So I suspect I left an instable mess behind and the second time the tutorial ran it crashed into this mess.

I erased everything and started over from unzipping and this third time there were no timeouts and the tutorial completed without error.

Answer (score 0):

File: /opt/solr/server/etc/jetty.xml

(1) Name="requestHeaderSize" set Property name "solr.jetty.request.header.size" default="81920"
(2) Name="responseHeaderSize"> set Property name="solr.jetty.response.header.size" default="81920"

(3) Restart Solr

Answer (score 0):

Hm, tried this, still getting the exact same error.

After Change:

```
[Set name="requestHeaderSize"][Property name="solr.jetty.request.header.size" default="81920" /][/Set]
[Set name="responseHeaderSize"][Property name="solr.jetty.response.header.size" default="81920" /][/Set]
```

I stopped everything and retried, then I had Windows Firewall prompt me for 'SAP Machine' authorization for java 11 message, I accepted it, and retried. Then it worked. Seems Windows Firewall related.

Answer (score 0):

Check the solr.in.sh config and make sure below configuration is uncommented and set as true
SOLR_SSL_ENABLED=true