# solr /update/extract 404 Not Found

Tags: docker-compose, solr, solr-cell

I'm encountering an issue while trying to upload documents to solr via the endpoint /update/extract.

I run solr 8.5.2 and zookeeper 3.5.8 in docker and could index data before via

```
...
solr.add(solr_documents)
```

My Setup:

The Filesystem (the django folder is not relevant for the Problem)

[image]

The Files in solr

[image]

The File in solr-config

[image]

I use the docker-compose.yaml (the django image isnt relevant for the problem)

```
version: "1.0"
services:
  solr:
    build:
      context: solr/.
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: aips-solr
    hostname: aips-solr
    ports:
      - 8983:8983
    environment:
      - ZK_HOST=aips-zk:2181
      - SOLR_HOST=aips-solr
    networks:
      - zk-solr
      - solr-django
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    volumes:
      - ./solr/solr-config:/opt/solr/server/solr/configsets/_default/conf

  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper:3.5.8
    container_name: aips-zk
    hostname: aips-zk
    ports:
      - 2181:2128
    networks:
      - zk-solr
      - solr-django
    restart: unless-stopped

  django:
    build:
      context: django/.
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: django
    hostname: django
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    depends_on:
      - solr
    volumes:
      - ./django/app:/app
    networks:
      - solr-django

networks:
  zk-solr:
  solr-django:
```

The Dockerfile contains:

```
FROM solr:8.5.2

USER root

ADD run_solr_w_ltr.sh ./run_solr_w_ltr.sh
RUN chown solr:solr run_solr_w_ltr.sh
RUN chmod u+x run_solr_w_ltr.sh


RUN chown -R solr:solr /opt/solr/

USER solr

ENTRYPOINT "./run_solr_w_ltr.sh"
```

the launch_sorl.sh contains  (to copy plugin learning to rank to solr)

```
#!/bin/sh 
mkdir -p /var/solr/data/lib/
cp dist/solr-ltr-*.jar /var/solr/data/lib/
ls /var/solr/data/lib

solr-foreground -Dsolr.ltr.enabled=true
```

the launch_solr.sh starts the container with

```
#!/bin/sh

docker build . -t aips-solr
```

Solr runs sucessfully and the admin center can be accessed via http://localhost:8983/solr/#/

I followed the instruction of https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_5/uploading-data-with-solr-cell-using-apache-tika.html

I did create an file called solrconfig.xml in the sub folder solr

[image]

The contant is:

```
<lib dir="/opt/solr/contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="/opt/solr/dist/" regex="solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />

<requestHandler name="/update/extract" 
                startup="lazy"
                class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler">
   <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="lowernames">true</str>
      <str name="fmap.content">content</str>
   </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

I checked if the solr folder exists and contains the files.

i created a new index in the solr-admin-center

[image]

i should be using the config of the directory

```
/opt/solr/server/solr/configsets/_default/conf
```

right ?

I set the volumn via

```
volumes:
      - ./solr/solr-config:/opt/solr/server/solr/configsets/_default/conf
```

therefore the config should be the config of solrconfig.xml

```
<lib dir="/opt/solr/contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="/opt/solr/dist/" regex="solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />

<requestHandler name="/update/extract" 
                startup="lazy"
                class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler">
   <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="lowernames">true</str>
      <str name="fmap.content">content</str>
   </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

right?

The Settings of Parser-Specific Properties are optional if i understand it correct.

If i call the endpoint /update/extract of the collection via the admin center

[image]

i get

[image]

If i use postmann

[image]

with the POST command and the uri: http://localhost:8983/solr/test10/update/extract

and the key Values:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| extractOnly | true |
| wt | json |
| stream.file | Zertifikate.pdf |
| stream.body | xaAgikF464R9gR7Jz7ACA0... (base64 string) |

I get also

[image]

Same if i use an adjusted curl command like in the docs

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update/extract?literal.id=doc6&defaultField=text&commit=true" --data-binary @example/exampledocs/sample.html -H 'Content-type:text/html'
```

What i tried so far

i change the path of the solr folder to a relativ path

solrconfig.xml

```
<lib dir="../../../../../solr/contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../../../solr/dist/" regex="solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />

<requestHandler name="/update/extract" 
                startup="lazy"
                class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler">
   <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="lowernames">true</str>
      <str name="fmap.content">content</str>
   </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

I checked if the folder solr contains the the .jars

I checked if i can access the Collection

[image]

i checked if the user solr has the right permissions

My setup must be wrong but I can't find any other clues on how to find and solve the error.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

**Based on MatsLindh's comment, I have made the following further changes.**

> According to the admin interface you're running Solr in in cloud mode - that means that you have to explicitly upload your config set to the running zookeeper instance. See solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/deployment-guide/… - you might want to run it as a single instance instance of using the built-in cluster support if you want to just have a single node and supply the configuration on the file system instead. By MatsLindh

I uploaded the confing with the follwing steps

1. I started docker with

```
docker-compose up
```

2. I uploaded the config via a 2. powershell with the command

`docker-compose exec solr solr zk upconfig -n newconfig -d /opt/solr/server/solr/configsets/_default/conf -z zookeeper:2181`

This will upload the configuration of the folder.
Afterwards the file solrconfig.xml had to be adapted as follows:

```
<config>
   <luceneMatchVersion>8.5.2</luceneMatchVersion>
   <lib dir="/opt/solr/contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
   <lib dir="/opt/solr/dist/" regex="solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />

   <requestHandler name="/update/extract" 
                  startup="lazy"
                  class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler">
      <lst name="defaults">
         <str name="lowernames">true</str>
         <str name="fmap.content">content</str>
      </lst>
   </requestHandler>
</config>
```

A schema.xml also needed to be created.
I used the schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema>
    <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" 
     positionIncrementGap="100"> 
        <analyzer type="index"> 
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" 
            words="stopwords.txt" />
           <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" 
            words="stopwords.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" 
            synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fields>
        <field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" 
        stored="true"/>
        <field name="content" type="text_general" indexed="true" 
        stored="true"/>
    </fields>
</schema>
```

Because of the schema the two text files
synonyms.txt and stopwords.txt had to be created.
After the changes my Folderstructure looks like
[image]
After all the changes i get the following error if i try to create a new collection with the configset:[image]

> Possibly unhandled rejection:
> {"data":{"responseHeader":{"status":400,"QTime":620},"failure":{"aips-solr:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error
> from server at http://aips-solr:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore
> 'test_upload_3_shard1_replica_n1': Unable to create core
> [test_upload_3_shard1_replica_n1] Caused by: null"},"Operation create
> caused
> exception:":"org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
> Underlying core creation failed while creating collection:
> test_upload_3","exception":{"msg":"Underlying core creation failed
> while creating collection:
> test_upload_3","rspCode":400},"error":{"metadata":["error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException","root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],"msg":"Underlying
> core creation failed while creating collection:
> test_upload_3","code":400}},"status":400,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"admin/collections","params":{"wt":"json","_":1687760309417,"action":"CREATE","name":"test_upload_3","router.name":"compositeId","numShards":1,"collection.configName":"newconfig","replicationFactor":1,"maxShardsPerNode":1,"autoAddReplicas":"false"},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json,
> text/plain,
> */*","X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"},"timeout":10000},"statusText":"Bad
> Request","xhrStatus":"complete","resource":{}}

I think it has to do with a network or firewall issue.
The guess is based on this stackoverflow post [Failed to create collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62601467/failed-to-create-collection-techproducts-due-to-underlying-core-creation-fail)

I will check it this evening on another pc.

Comment: According to the admin interface you're running Solr in in cloud mode - that means that you have to explicitly upload your config set to the running zookeeper instance. See https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/deployment-guide/solr-in-docker.html#creating-collections - you might want to run it as a single instance instance of using the built-in cluster support if you want to just have a single node and supply the configuration on the file system instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. :) 
The config did indeed have to be uploaded. 
Where did you find the info ? 
Does the info come from a deeper understanding of the article https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/deployment-guide/docker-networking.html ?

Comment: It's mentioned in passing in the last sentence in the section I linked in my comment, but also because of knowledge that when you're using Solr in cloud mode, configuration is not read directly from disk (since it needs to be shared among nodes).

Comment: The actual server log should have more details about the underlying reason why the core creation failed - since you're referencing libraries with a local path I might guess that it doesn't want to / can't find the libraries. You might want to follow https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/configuration-guide/libs.html#lib-directories to try one of the other methods for adding libraries in that case.